# Cannot print the custom paper size in crystal report c#

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I am trying to print custom paper size (8.5in Wt. x 5.5in Ht.)
My Printer does not allow to create custom paper size when Width greater than Height. So I decided to do it dynamically through c#. Here are the steps I have done. 
**Step1:-** Created a custom paper size from `Print Server Properties` under `Devices And Printers`and named it `JVD` [image]

**Step2:-** My C# Code

```
using (DataSet Ds = GetPrintDetails(Dt, Con))
                    {
                        HospDataSet.Tables["ME_ProductSale"].Merge(Ds.Tables[0]);
                        HospDataSet.Tables["ME_ProductSale_Detail"].Merge(Ds.Tables[1]);
                        HospDataSet.Tables["ME_Identity"].Merge(Ds.Tables[2]);
                        ReportPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports_ME\\rptProductSale.rpt";                        
                        rptDoc.Load(ReportPath);
                        rptDoc.SetDataSource(HospDataSet);
                        PrintDocument PD = new PrintDocument();                                                                                               
                        for (int i = 0; i <= PD.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1; i++)
                        {                            
                            if (PD.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].PaperName == "JVD")
                            {
                                rptDoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = (CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize)PD.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].RawKind;                                                                
                                break;
                            }
                        }                        
                        rpvHospitalReportViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc;
                        rpvHospitalReportViewer.Refresh();                        
                    }
```

But still not able to print custom paper size. What I am doing wrong ?
Any help wil be appreciable.

Comment: Please help guys, this is a very serious issue.

Comment: Have you tried creating the custom page size as 5.5 width by 8.5 height, then after choosing the page size in your Crystal Report change the orientation to landscape?